# How draw an open line or unclosed path pixi.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixi.js

I am trying to draw a zig-zagged line across the canvas with a 6px colored stroke with no fill. However the shape is always closed and connects an unwanted line back to the origin. How can I prevent pixi.js from closing the path.

```
  @line = new PIXI.Graphics
  @line.lineStyle(6, color)
  stage.addChild(@line)

  @line.moveTo markX,markY

  for row, col in rows
    @line.lineTo(@getSymbolX(col)-spanDistance, @getSymbolY(row))
    @line.lineTo(@getSymbolX(col)+spanDistance, @getSymbolY(row))

  @line.lineTo(@getSymbolX(4) + 60, @getSymbolY(rows[4]))
  @line.lineStyle(0, color)
```

[image]

> PIXI 3.07 has introduced a bug https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/1892 a workaround solution is to use the following **graphics.currentPath.shape.closed = false**

Comment: you need it to in pixi.js or plain canvas api also good to go?

Comment: In pixi,js would be preferable. But I have just discovered that there is a bug in PIXI 3.07. https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/1892.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`@line.currentPath.shape.closed = false;`

https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/2014

EDIT: Or in 2022:

`graphics.currentPath.closeStroke = false;`